# How to make CSS Grid Container Always Fill Available Vertical Space

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, css-grid

I have a simplified version of an issue I am having. I have a container which I put items into. The container is set up as `display: grid` and **I want it to always fill all available vertical space regardless of what is in it.**

For illustration I have a simple CodeSandbox here. My question is :

1. Why does the container (in grey) not fill all available space despite setting `height: 100%` ?
   (I also tried `height: 100vh` here but it ended up stretching the elements inside also)
2. When I remove something from the container (i.e. Click "Remove Card" button), why does it shrink ?

```
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/styles";
import React, { useState } from "react";
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  cardContainerRootStyle: {
    gridTemplateColumns: "repeat(auto-fit, minmax(348px, 1fr))",
    justifyItems: "center",
    display: "grid",
    gridGap: "1rem",
    margin: "0 auto",
    padding: 15,
    height: "100%"
  }
});

export default function App() {
  const styles = useStyles();
  const [cardCurrentlyDisplayed, setCardCurrentlyDisplayed] = useState([
    <Paper
      style={{ minHeight: "200px", minWidth: "200px", backgroundColor: "blue" }}
    />
  ]);

  return (
    <>
      <Button variant="outlined" onClick={() => setCardCurrentlyDisplayed([])}>
        Remove Card
      </Button>
      <Paper
        style={{ backgroundColor: "grey" }}
        square={true}
        classes={{
          root: styles.cardContainerRootStyle
        }}
      >
        {cardCurrentlyDisplayed}
      </Paper>
    </>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit minimumHeightGrid]

**Updated 9th March 2020 - Solution**  - https://codesandbox.io/s/minimumheightgrid-nh2oq

Comment: My first question is "100% of what"?

Comment: The 100% must refer upwards to the parent to determine that. If the superior height is not quantifiable, your property will fail. - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575141/how-to-make-a-div-100-height-of-the-browser-window

Comment: 100% of the parent div. So you mean the parent div needs to be 100% also ?

Comment: Yep, you need to make sure that the 100% can be quantified. If the container is the ultimate parent then the `html` and `body` need to have 100% height/min-height also.

Comment: Have forked my pen and ensure that the parent(with red border) is larger than my container. Still the same issue - https://codesandbox.io/s/minimumheightgrid-rjvzg

Comment: ...and the `#root` div...and the `html/body` elements all have 100%...right?

Comment: Not explicitly no. I thought it should at least just fill up its parent seeing as the space is there.

Comment: Got a solution. See answer below -https://codesandbox.io/s/minimumheightgrid-nh2oq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got a solution - https://codesandbox.io/s/minimumheightgrid-nh2oq

Change the following on the container (grey)

```
    minHeight: "100vh",
    height: "auto"
```

and on the element (blue)

```
maxHeight: "200px"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure that the blue square fill all the space when it is render alone in the grid. You just need to give your blue squace a width of 100% and let the grid css take care of the rest.

Here the link of the forked sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/minimumheightgrid-i494m

NB: if i misunderstood your problem don't hesitate to tell me.

Comment: I want the grey container (which contains the blue square) to always fill all available vertical space on the page (regardless of what is in it)

Comment: It already take all the space available by his parent container, if you want the grey part to take more space you need to give a bigger height for his parent container. What size the grey part should have all the screen or another set height ?

Comment: I have given a bigger height for the parent container in my forked CodeSandbox here - http://codesandbox.io/s/minimumheightgrid-rjvzg. Still the same issue.

Comment: Yes sorry, i forgot i had the grid-template-rows css property in my codesandbox. is it what you were looking for ? https://codesandbox.io/s/minimumheightgrid-3irxw

Comment: No unfortunately not. I had something similar myself. I want the blue box to remain the same constant size (i.e. 200px * 200px) and only it's container (grey box) to fill available space.

Comment: Here i updated the sandbox a little max-height and max-width did the trick

Comment: I got a solution. See my answer. https://codesandbox.io/s/minimumheightgrid-nh2oq